# Display and manage (CRUD) point cloud in (Geo)Django 2

Tags: geodjango, geolocation, django, point-cloud

I would like to use GeoDjango to

1. Geolocate the place I will scan.
2. Would start to 3D scans with a DIY lidar based on Arduino/Rpi.

So far no worries. Then,

1. The Goal is to save x,y,z as input in PostgreSQL DB (PostGIS
   extension?, pointcloud extension?) with Django ORM
2. Then display it in ThreeJs, Cesium
   or Potree with Django if supported.

What's the best way and the support for this technologies?

Comment: I have found this project https://github.com/ricleal/DjangoPlotLy but not a complete solution

Comment: Model with point cloud on old version of django: https://github.com/julfla/master_project/blob/master/django_server/pointcloud/models.py

Comment: This one looks more complete: https://github.com/ngageoint/voxel-globe